# Running promises in small concurrent batches (no more than X at a time)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

The Async library has functions like [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) which can be used to efficiently spread a big batch of jobs over multiple CPU cores, like this:

```
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

async.eachLimit(someArray, numCPUs, function (value, done) {
  exec('something --input' + value, done);
}, finalCallback);
```

This avoids overloading the system with too many commands at once, but still exploits multiple CPUs.

I want to do the same thing but with Promises.

In the [Bluebird API](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md), I can't see any obvious way to do this kind of batching in such a concise, expressive way as with Async.

Is there a good pattern for doing this with Bluebird (or with Promises generally)? Or any other utility library I could use for this?

Comment: It can be done without dependencies too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213316/execute-batch-of-promises-in-series-once-promise-all-is-done-go-to-the-next-bat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Bluebird, you can use [`Promise.map` function with the `concurrency` option](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-concurrency), like this

```
require('bluebird').map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function (currentNumber) {
    console.log(currentNumber);
    return Promise.delay(currentNumber * 2, 1000);
}, {concurrency: 2}).then(console.error.bind(console));
```

Now, you can see that it is processing two values at a time. The value being processed may be in a different order, but the items in the result array will be in the same order corresponding to the original array.

PS: I introduced a delay of 1 second with `Promise.delay`, so that we can observe what is being processed currently.

---

**Demo**

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

  Promise.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(currentNumber) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += currentNumber + "<br />";
    return Promise.delay(currentNumber * 2, 1000);
  }, {
    concurrency: parseInt(document.getElementById("concurrency").value, 10)
  }).then(function(result) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += result + "<br />";
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/2.9.27/bluebird.min.js"></script>
Limit: <input id="concurrency" value="2" />
<input type="button" onclick="start()" value="Start" />
<pre id="result" />
```

Comment: But how does this utilize CPU cores?

Comment: The only way javascript is going to utilize multiple CPU cores is if each promise spawns a command process and waits for it to finish.