# Invoking an array functions that return promises in order without external dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**Without the use of any extra libraries (async, bluebird etc)** I am trying to implement a function that returns a promise resolves (or rejects) based on an array of functions that return promises as an input parameter... `Promise.all(iterable)` has very similar functionality to what I am trying to accomplish exepct the promises in the `iterable` parameter of `Promise.all` do not execute in sequential order.

I could simply chain these functions together however what if `functionList`was a list of unkown length...

I have attemped to conceptually show what I am trying to accomplish below:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        return resolve();
       }, 200);
  })
}

function bar() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        return resolve();
       }, 200);
  })
}

function baz() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        return reject();
       }, 100);
  })
}

const functionList = [foo, bar, baz];

function promiseSeries(functionList){
    const results = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      promiseList.map((promise, i) => {
        return new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
          promise()
            .then((result) => {
              results.push(result);
              if (i === promiseList.length - 1) {
                return resolve(results);
              }
               else return _resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => error)
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Obviously with running Promise.all on functionList we will see that baz (even though its position is functionList[2] ***resolves first***)

Neither [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence) or [Running promises in small concurrent batches (no more than X at a time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708383/running-promises-in-small-concurrent-batches-no-more-than-x-at-a-time) provide answers to this question. I do not want to import a library to handle this single utility function and mostly I am just curious as to what this function would look like.

Comment: Without any other libraries, You need to do a recursion for this, since you need to wait for one promise to complete, an example (sorry, can also post it as comment) :

const recurse = (promiseList) => {
 if (promiseList.length > 0) {
  promiseList[0]().then(v =>
   recurse(promiseList.splice(1, promiseList.length))
  )
 }
}

Comment: Array#reduce is good for this sort of thing

Comment: @Max its unclear to me how that works... I also tired invoking that function with an array of valid promises and the promise chain never resolves... perhaps you could post a formal answer / fiddle

Comment: Super frustrating this is NOT a duplicate of "how do I use bluebird to run promises in a series"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jbnhLtvk/2/ should give you the idea.
Basically, you need to wait for one promise to complete, and then call recursive function but without the head of the array, so in the end the array will be empty and the function will terminate.

Comment: @MaxwellLasky - indeed it would be seeing as you specifically want a pure solution, no libraries ... maybe [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgvhzn9s/) will help you

Comment: @Max its not super clear to me how your solution handles a promise rejection... I would expect your recurse function to return a promise in order to handle errors or resolve according to the inputted promise arr

Comment: Its updated here, https://jsfiddle.net/jbnhLtvk/4/

Comment: What about using Promise.all() ?

Comment: @Oreste please read the question... Promise.all() does not execute an array of promises in order but rather invokes them all synchronously

Comment: @thefourtheye pretty ridiculous that you marked this as a duplicate of a question you already answered that is basically completely unrelated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Comment: *There is a similar question on stack overflow currently but it relates to this question in the context of an external dependency.* What question would that be?

Comment: The question that @TamasHegedus linked to in the comment above is the question I had in mind... (I am not trying to accomplish this task using Q or bluebird)

Comment: @Max if you post your answer I will mark it as correct seeing as your solution was truly the best answer

Comment: Yeap, sure will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice and clean way to achieve this without any extra libraries is using recursion. An example:

```
const p1 = () => Promise.resolve(10);
const p2 = () => Promise.resolve(20);
const p3 = () => Promise.resolve(30);

const promiseList = [p1, p2, p3];

const sequencePromises = (promises) => {
  const sequence = (promises, results) => {
    if (promises.length > 0) {
      return promises[0]()
        .then(res => sequence(promises.splice(1, promises.length), results.concat(res)))
        .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(results);
    }
  }
  return sequence(promises, []);
}

sequencePromises(promiseList)
   .then(res => console.log(res))
   .catch(err => console.log("ERROR"));
```

Comment: @Maxwell  `.catch(err => Promise.reject(err));` is a no-op (that's tech-talk for "doesn't do anything").

Comment: @torazaburo Just remove it then, I didn't notice when I was writing the code. Another way, `catch` is useful is if he wants to continue the promise even if there's one failure.

Answer (score 1):

This is not more complicated than:

```
funcs.reduce((prev, cur) => prev.then(cur), Promise.resolve())
```

A recursive version, which return an array of the resolved values:

```js
function recurse([first, ...last], init) {
  if (!first) return Promise.resolve([]);
  return first(init)
    .then(value => 
      recurse(last, value)
        .then(values => [value, ...values])
    );
}

// Testing function to return a function which
// returns a promise which increments its value.
const x = v => y => Promise.resolve(v + y);
    
recurse([x(1), x(2)], 0).then(console.log);
```

Comment: If A and B are functions that return promises I am confused as to how your first example is not dramatically different than using `Promise.all()`... With `Promise.all()` both functions are invoked synchronously (as opposed to B waiting for A to resolve)

Comment: `const recurse = (promises, results) => {
  if (promises.length > 0) {
    return promises[0]()
      .then((res) => 
        recurse(promises.splice(1, promises.length), results.concat(res)))
      .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(results);
  }
}` is the function that ended up serving my needs...

Comment: What bothers me about both of these answers is that in both cases if  the promise returned by any of functions rejects it will silently fail - both of these solutions implicitly assume that every promise returned will be "thenable"...

Comment: @Maxwell What do you want to happen? In either case, the end result will a be a promise in rejected state (the reason being the reason for the promise which was rejected), which can be handled via `catch`. I can't think of any more reasonable behavior. So eg `recurse(blah).then(/*all promises fulfilled*/).catch(/*one promise was rejected*/)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just chain them, starting with a null promise:

```
const promises = [foo, bar, baz];
let result = Promise.resolve();
promises.forEach(promise => result = result.then(() => promise));
return result;
```

As Ali pointed out, you can use a reduction instead but you need to use functions in the then calls:

```
return promises.reduce(
    (result, promise) => result.then(() => promise),
    Promise.resolve()
);
```

You can omit the initial value if you know that promises is not empty.

However if you really want to do things in sequence, you often want to deal with an array of functions that return a promise. For example:

```
return ids.map(id => () => processId(id))
.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
promises.reduce((previous, promise) => {
  if (previous) {
    return previous.then(() => promise);
  }
  return promise;
}, null)
```